# Twilio API Error RestException: Missing Parameter MessageFlow, but the parameter is not missing

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

When using the client.messaging.v1.services().usAppToPerson.create() end point I am getting this error:

```
RestException [Error]: Missing required parameter MessageFlow in the post body,
Status: 400,
Code: 20001,
```

I have tried just about every different way to format messageFlow in the body but no matter what I do this error comes up.

This is my code:

```
const serviceData = {
          message_flow: "REMOVED-THIS-STRING-FOR-STACKOVERFLOW",
          description: "REMOVED-THIS-STRING-FOR-STACKOVERFLOW",
          messageSamples: ["REMOVED-THIS-STRING-FOR-STACKOVERFLOW"],
          usAppToPersonUsecase: "SOLE_PROPRIETOR",
          hasEmbeddedLinks: true,
          hasEmbeddedPhone: true,
          brandRegistrationSid: brandSid,
        };
        client.messaging.v1.services(service.sid)
            .usAppToPerson
            .create(
                serviceData,
            )
```

I have also tried changing message_flow to the following:

- `messageFlow:`
- `MessageFlow:`
- `messageflow:`
- `Message_Flow:`
- `"MessageFlow":`
- `"messageFlow":`
- `"message_flow":`

If someone has ever dealt with this before please help me out!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/api/us-a2p-campaign-resource), it should be `messageFlow`.

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messaging.v1.services('MGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
  .usAppToPerson
  .create({
     messageFlow: 'End users opt-in by visiting www.example.com and adding their phone number. They then check a box agreeing to receive text messages from Example Brand. Additionally, end users can also opt-in by texting START to (111) 222-3333 to opt in. Term and Conditions at www.example.com/tc. Privacy Policy at www.example.com/privacy',
     messageSamples: ['EXPRESS: Denim Days Event is ON. Reply STOP to unsubscribe.', 'LAST CHANCE: Book your next flight for just 1 (ONE) EUR'],
     brandRegistrationSid: 'BNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     description: 'description',
     usAppToPersonUsecase: 'us_app_to_person_usecase',
     hasEmbeddedLinks: true,
     hasEmbeddedPhone: true
   })
  .then(us_app_to_person => console.log(us_app_to_person.sid));
```

I see you mentioned that you tried this option, but I assume you got another error message then.